# Why I'm being redirected when accessing specific site in my network?

Tags: router, dns, routing

A few days ago, I started to be redirected when I try to access **one specific site** (of a government agency) in **my home WIFI network**. So far I only noticed this on that agency website. This happens in both my smartphone and my laptop.

Site: http://www.inmet.gov.br

I'm redirected to the following address: "http://flbktrk.com/?s=&d=parrz.com&r=PLE&ref="

I can access the referred website in my office network and my mobile 4G network without any problems.

That problem doesn't occur when I'm using a VPN.

Comment: I can confirm that I can reach this site/URL from europe and are not redirected.

Comment: Thanks. Turns out it was really a DNS problem. It got fixed when I switched to Google's 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 DNS, as suggested by @Phoenix. I still don't understand why the original DNS suddenly started failing, and only for this website, though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your DNS router to any DNS servers other than your ISP. There is no side effect except you may need to clear DNS cache to get updated records. Also, don't forget to restart the router. If that is not the case, change your router configuration.